# Hibernate and multiThread Logic

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, hql

Im working on a java standAlone project. I need to use hibernate in a MultiThread application but i just cant figure it out how to set up this correctly.

Each Thread deals with the same process of the others.

Everything goes Ok when i run it in a Non-Async way, but when i call the same thing using threads, hibernate just don't work fine.

Can anyone please explain me what's the correct way to use Hibernate in a multiThread Java Stand-Alone App?

**Hibernate Util**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final Session session;

static {
    try {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("middleware.properties"));
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
        cfg.addProperties(properties);
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    } catch (IOException | HibernateException he) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, DataBaseMessage.CONNECTION_ERROR.getMessage(),              DataBaseMessage.CONNECTION_ERROR.getTitle(),JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);          
    }  
}
public static Session getSession() {
    return session;
}
```

**The Error comes here**

TbHistoDespachos despacho = Dao.findDespachoByTagId(element.getChild("tagID").getText());

```
public synchronized List<TbHistoDespachos> ExractDespachoAndNotify(String data, String nombreConexion) {
    List<TbHistoDespachos> despachos = new ArrayList<>();
    String nombreConexionUpp = nombreConexion.toUpperCase();
    try {
        Document doc = convertStringToDocument(data);
        if (!doc.getRootElement().getChild("reply").getChild("readTagIDs")
                .getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            for (Element element : doc.getRootElement().getChild("reply").
                    getChild("readTagIDs").getChild("returnValue")
                    .getChildren()) {
                TbHistoDespachos despacho = Dao.findDespachoByTagId(element.getChild("tagID").getText());
                if (despacho != null) {
                    if(evaluateDespacho(nombreConexionUpp, despacho)){
                        despachos.add(despacho);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JDOMException | IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, FilesMessageWarnings.NOTIFICATION_SAP_WARNING.
                getMessage().replace("&nombreConexion", nombreConexion).replace("&tagID", ""),
                FilesMessageWarnings.NOTIFICATION_SAP_WARNING.getTitle(), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    return despachos;
}
```

**Here is the DAO**

```
public class Dao {

private static Session sesion;
public static TbHistoDespachos findDespachoByTagId(String tagId) {
    TbHistoDespachos despacho = null;
    try {
        startTransmission();
        despacho = (TbHistoDespachos)sesion.createQuery("FROM TbHistoDespachos WHERE TAG_ID =:tagId")
                .setParameter("tagId", tagId)
                .uniqueResult();
        stopTransmission();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.out.println("error: " + he.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, DataBaseMessage.QUERY_ERROR.getMessage(),
                DataBaseMessage.QUERY_ERROR.getTitle(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return despacho;
}
private static void startTransmission() {

    sesion = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    sesion.getTransaction().begin();

}
private static void stopTransmission() {

    sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    sesion.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close();
    sesion.clear();

}
```

ANY IDEAS?

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: the problem that i dont know what's the correct design to implement Hibernate on a standalone application

Comment: Is there an Exception? What is the difference in outcome between the 2 invocations?

Comment: Yes, mostly nested transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from `static Session` variables. A `SessionFactory` is thread-safe and, generally speaking, you only need one (static) instance per database. A `Session`, on the other hand, is not thread-safe and is usually created (using a `SessionFactory`) and discarted/closed on the fly.

To solve your immediate problem, remove the `static Session sesion` variable from your Dao and also 'inline' the `startTransmission` and `stopTransmission` methods in the `findDespachoByTagId` method. This will ensure that each thread calling `findDespachoByTagId` creates and uses its own session instance. To analyze the current problem, imagine two threads calling `findDespachoByTagId` at the same time. Now the static session variable will be assigned a value twice by the `startTransmission` method. This means one session instance is lost almost immediatly after it was created while the other one is used by two threads at the same time. Not a good thing.

But there are other problems too: there are no `finally` blocks that guarantee transactions are closed and database connections are released (via the closing of sessions). Also, you will probably want to use a database pool as the one provided by Hibernate is not suitable for production. I recommend you have a look at [HibHik](https://github.com/intercommit/hibhik): I created this project to show a minimal stand-alone Java application using Hibernate with a database pool (HikariCP) that uses the recommended patterns and practices (mostly shown in [TestDbCrud.java](https://github.com/intercommit/hibhik/blob/master/src/test/java/com/descartes/hibhik/TestDbCrud.java)). Use the relevant parts in your application, than write multi-threaded unit-tests to verify your database layer (DAO) is working properly, even in the case of failure (e.g. when the database is suddenly no longer available because the network-cable was unplugged).