# Update same object with collection in multiple sessions?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

So i was trying to implement proper multithreading for saving and update operation in hibernate.
Each of my threads uses one newly created session with its own transaction.
Some Entities are shared over multiple sessions.

- Update "Chunk:1" in session 1 on thread 1
- Update "Chunk:1" in session 2 on thread 2

I always get a "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open session in Chunk.inChunk" exception, is there a way to ignore that exception and simply force the sessions to save/update the shared entities ? I have no idea what hibernate would prevent from doing so.

This code basically gets executed on multiple threads at the "same" time.

```java
            var session = database.openSession();  // sessionFactory.openSession()
            session.beginTransaction();

            try {

                // Save my entities
                for (var identity : identities)
                    session.update(identity);

                session.flush();
                session.clear();
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception e){
                GameExtension.getInstance().trace("Update");
                GameExtension.getInstance().trace(e.getMessage());
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }


            session.close();
```

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Chunk{

   public List<Player> inChunk;
}
```

Any idea how i could solve this issue ?

Comment: don't know about forcing, but of plenty of statements discouraging handling of one entity in multiple sessions/threads simultaneously, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979089/hibernate-and-multithread-logic).

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev Thanks ! Well i read that its simply not possible... but i cant image this, because why shouldnt multiple threads be able to update the same entity ? Theres literally no real reason why this shouldnt work

Comment: what about cloning the collection, so every session gets another instance with identical data? perhaps that's what you do anyway ... just out of curiosity, do you expect an rdbms via hibernate orm to be performant enough for a game server?

Comment: but I think, the non thread safety of hibernate is limited for a session, so 2 sessions should be ok in different threads. so it should be possible to have one entity in both sessions and attach a collection in both cases, just not the identical collection perhaps

Comment: I could try to clone that collection, thats a good idea... Currently im only using hibernate because its easier then writing my own queries ^^ in the near future i will probably save every few minutes instead of all little changes, thats how normal games do it.

Comment: but this way you also will write the same collection twice to the db, pretty expensive. I think every element makes for an insert or update statement.

Comment: "Theres literally no real reason" yes, there is. Your view of the entity is transactional, and you are trying to share that same data and modify it in two separate transactions. What do you expect to happen if one thread makes a change to that object and rolls back? Are those changes reflected in session 2 or not? Break up your logic and/or model into smaller parts so that multithreaded concurrency logic will never overlap or you are bound to hit major issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a similar question a few days ago. Here the link: [Multithreading Exception : "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707286/multithreading-exception-illegal-attempt-to-associate-a-collection-with-two-o/64711851#64711851)

The issue you are facing is that you load an entity with a collection with session 1 and then somehow this object is passed to session 2 while the object is still associated to an open session 1. This simply does not work, even in a single threaded environment.

Either detach the object from the session 1 or reload the object in session 2.